# Extract text from filename in shiny app and add to data frame before writing back to local machine

Tags: r, regex, string, shiny, shinyapps

I would like to be able to convert a scrip I use in my workflow to a shinyapp for other nonusers to use. I'm new to shiny in general and using Rstudio. I was able to get the basic functionality to work but am struggling to extract specific strings to add them as an id column as I have in the sourced script.

this is the function I would like to have implemented in my shiny app

```
##### function to read tab-separated flat file(s) while adding a string from the filename to a column in the table
my_read_tsv <- function(x) {
  out <- read_tsv(x, skip = 4) ## skips for header lines
  id_code <-
    paste(
      str_extract(x, "[0-9]{1,6}), 
      str_extract(x, "[A-Za-z0-9]{1,3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}_[A-Za-z0-9]{1,3}")
    )
  cbind(ID = id_code, out)
}
```

in my script i define the function then call it in lapply like below

```
tbl <- lapply(desiredlist, my_read_tsv) %>% bind_rows()
```

below is what I was able to get to work partially so far but the "id" column is filled with "NANA" values.

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Combine files"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                fileInput("fileinput",
                          "Choose files from a directory",
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          accept=c('text/csv', 
                                   'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                   '.csv')),
                downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
            ),
            mainPanel(
                tableOutput('contents')
            )
        )
    )
)

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 200*1024^2) ## scales file size above 5mb limit
server <-  function(input, output) {
    getData <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$fileinput
        if (is.null(inFile)){
            return(NULL)
        }else {  
            csvfiles <- lapply(inFile$datapath, function(y){
                    out <- read_tsv(y, skip = 4)
                    id_code <-
                        paste(
                            str_extract(y,"WR[0-9]{1,6}"),
                            str_extract(y, "[A-Za-z0-9]{1,3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}_[A-Za-z0-9]{1,3}")
                        )
                    cbind(ID = id_code, out)
                }
            )
            do.call(bind_rows, csvfiles)
        }
    })
    output$contents <- renderTable( 
        getData() 
    )
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() { 
            paste("combined_file", ".csv", sep="")
        },
        content = function(file) { 
            write.csv(getData(), file, row.names=FALSE)   
        })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Example data has 4 header rows, then row titles, then numerical data in columns 1:6

```
EX:
header
header
header 
header
row.names 
1   2    3    4    5    6
1   2    3    4    5    6
```

Comment: Is there a method to view the list generated by selecting the files? I assume the issue is due to the list not being a format that allows extraction by regular expression?

Comment: I am able to use the browser() to find the source of the issue. The file path is stored in a tmp location and loses the filename needed for the regular expression to extract it. is it possible to coerce the file name to remain the same as it is on my machine when uploaded?

Comment: solved by debugging.... needed to reference the name column not datapath. inFile$datapath works when changed to inFile$name